# "object Object" showing as input value with Formik forms on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, object, default, formik

With `Formik`, my input shows an `[object Object]` value instead of behaving in a standard manner.

[Code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-v3-cbk8g).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import "./styles.css";

const SignupForm = () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "" }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object({
        email: Yup.string()
          .email("Mauvais e-mail")
          .required("Champ requis")
      })}
      onSubmit={values => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
    >
      <Form>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <ErrorMessage name="email" />
        <br />
        <Field name="email" type="email" />
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<SignupForm />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Formik` matches the initial values to the `name` of the field, not the `id`.

Try using this as your `Field`:

`<Field name="email" id="email" type="email" />`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import "./styles.css";

const SignupForm = () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "" }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object({
        email: Yup.string()
          .email("Mauvais e-mail")
          .required("Champ requis")
      })}
      onSubmit={values => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
    >
      {props => (
        <Form>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <ErrorMessage name="email" />
          <br />
          <Field
            name="email"
            id="email"
            type="email"
            onChange={e => {
              props.setTouched({ email: true });
              props.handleChange(e);
            }}
          />
          <button type="submit">OK</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<SignupForm />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

You can also check the docs for more info on [`Field`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field)

Comment: Awesome thank you ! It works but for the onBlur event by default. I looked at the docs but I'm confused : is there any way to make it validate the input on each key stroke ? I'd like to fire validation on the onchange event

Comment: The problem is, that the validation is happening. But the component `ErrorMessage` only shows the error, when the field is `touched`. And it's only `touched`, once you `blur` the field. I have update the Codepen in my answer to set the `touched` value to true `onChange`. This works.. alternatively you could use the advanced usage of `Field`: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field#render and write your own Error Component. (See last example in the link),

Comment: Thank you Daniel for all your time spent on my issue. I understand what you mean, but I checked at the modified codepen and now it doesn't seem to work, even on Blur(). On the console, there's an error saying : Warning: An unhandled error was caught during validation in <Formik validationSchema />

Comment: are you using this one: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-v3-9osr2 ? Works fine for me.

Comment: This is so strange ! I double checked but I use the same and there is this error for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
console.log('form values:'+ JSON.stringify(formik.values));
```